# Why my swipper 3d slider is not working properly when I make a for loop in Django?

Tags: python, django, for-loop

```
{% extends 'elections/base.html'%}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                     <div class="row candidate_details">
                         {% for president in presidents %}
                         <div class="card">
                             {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
                             <div class="card-body">
                                 <img src="{{president.imageURL}}" alt="profile image" 
                                   class="profile-img1">
                                 <h1>{{president.first_name}} {{president.last_name}}</h1>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                             {% else %}
                             {% endif %}
                             <div class="card">
                                 <div class="card-body">
                                     <h1>Incoming Results</h1>
                                     <hr>
                                     <h2>Total Votes</h2>
                                     <h1>1,233,333 votes</h1>
                                     <hr>
                                     <h1>36%</h1>
                                     <hr>
                                 </div>  
                             </div>
                             {% endfor %}
                     </div>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
  
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
       
    <script>
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        effect: 'coverflow',
        grabCursor: true,
        centeredSlides: true,
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        coverflowEffect: {
        rotate: 30,
        stretch: 0,
        depth: 500,
        modifier: 1,
        slideShadows: true,
      },
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
        },
    });
     
    </script>

{% endblock content %}
```

I want to have a 3d slider of images and data in the description area.
I want to display the image of a candidate and his details for
each candidate one at time on each slide as shown in this image:

[image: 1]

Comment: We need the details what problem you have with your code and what exactly is not working. "It is not working" is not informative. That's the information we seek from you. Imagine yourself at the other side of the wire. Would you understand what is the problem?

Comment: What I want is that I want to render images in the slider one at a time in a row as someone slides the swipper. Am using a for a loop to retrieve data.

Comment: Yes, I understand but *why* does it not work with your code? What is your actual result and how is that different from what you want to achieve?

Comment: Well..What i want to achieve is in the image above. What am getting is that the cards turn out to be in columns down instead of being viewed after sliding.